# Switching between config files in C#

Tags: c#, app-config, configuration-files

Here I have two `config` files, I need to switch between these `config` files in `C#`

Example:

1. `app.config`
2. `address.config`

I need to change from `app.config` to `address.config` in runtime for fetching data.

I tried the below code:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config
    = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.AppSettings.File = runtimeconfigfile;
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: Why? Why would you need to change configuration in the middle of execution?

Comment: can you not just load "address.config" as an xml file and read the nodes that you need without unloading app.config?

Comment: I need some data from that config file.

Comment: Then why not include it as part of your `app.config`? Or use [`configSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) if it must be a separate file?

Comment: To show the difference between the data within config files.

Comment: You've waited just 18 minutes for others to answer your question, for free, and you're complaining? Unbelievable!

Comment: I'm not complaining, the thing I can't believe that I have asked a question that takes time to answer.  Sorry for that.  thanks Tomfanning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = strConfigPath };
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

When you want to switch files, you can change the ExeConfigFileName, and open mapped configuration again.

Comment: It is the path to the location of your config file.